# Reproducing Spring Data Rest search controllers in Spring Boot 2.3

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

Until Spring Boot 2.0, I could reproduce the controllers generated for query methods exposed by a mongodb repository.
Here is a code sample:

Domain Entity

```
@Document(collection = "foos")
public class Foo {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;

    // getters/setters omitted
}
```

Mongo repository

```
public interface FooRepository extends MongoRepository<Foo, String> {

    public Page<Foo> findByName(@Param("name") String name, Pageable pageable);

}
```

Spring Boot automatically exposes the search method through `/foos/search/findByName?name=...` with a result similar to this:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "foos" : [ {
      "name" : "qc",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/foos/56a8a8d5daffd28c9c907974"
        },
        "foo" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/foos/56a8a8d5daffd28c9c907974"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/foos/search/findByName?name=qc&page=0&size=20"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 1,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

I could reproduce it with the following custom controller and configuration

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("foos")
@RequiredArgsConstructor // lombok
public class FooQueryController {

    private final FooRepository repository;
    private final PagedResourcesAssembler pagedResourcesAssembler;

    @GetMapping(value = "search/query",
                produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UT8_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity custom(@RequestParam("name") String name,
                                      Pageable pageable,
                                      PersistentEntityResourceAssembler resourceAssembler) {
        var page = repository.findByName(name, pageable);
        var model = pagedResourcesAssembler.toResource(page, resourceAssembler);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(model);
    }

}

// Enables injecting a PersistentEntityResourceAssembler  in a RestController
// see https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-657 for details
@Configuration
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    // WARNING: do NOT change the name of this member - it is injected with the
    //          RequestMappingHandlerAdapter$repositoryExporterHandlerAdapter().
    private final RequestMappingHandlerAdapter repositoryExporterHandlerAdapter;

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(
            List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> customArgumentResolvers =
                repositoryExporterHandlerAdapter.getCustomArgumentResolvers();
        argumentResolvers.addAll(customArgumentResolvers);
    }

}
```

With this I can send a request to `/foos/search/query?name=...` and get the expected response:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "foos" : [ {
      "name" : "qc",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/foos/56a8a8d5daffd28c9c907974"
        },
        "foo" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/foos/56a8a8d5daffd28c9c907974"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/foos/search/query?name=qc&page=0&size=20"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 1,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

Switching to Spring Boot 2.3, using the Spring HATEOAS 1.0 API in the controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("foos")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FooQueryController {

    private final FooRepository repository;
    private final PagedResourcesAssembler pagedResourcesAssembler;

    @GetMapping(value = "search/query",
                produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity custom(@RequestParam("name") String name,
                                      Pageable pageable,
                                      PersistentEntityResourceAssembler resourceAssembler) {
        var page = repository.findByName(name, pageable);
        var model = pagedResourcesAssembler.toModel(page, resourceAssembler);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(model);
    }

}
```

I now get the following result:

```
{"_embedded":{"foos":[{"id":"56a8a8d5daffd28c9c907974","name":"qc","embeddeds":{},"nested":false,"persistentEntity":{"idProperty":{"name":"id","rawType":"java.lang.String","association":false,"owner":{"idProperty":{"name":"id","rawType":"java.lang.String","association":false,"owner":{"idProperty":{"name":"id","rawType":"java.lang.String","association":false,"owner":{"idProperty":{"name":"id","rawType":"java.lang.String","association":false,"owner":{"idProperty":{"name":"id","rawType":"java.lang.String","association":false,"owner":{"idProperty":{"name":"id","rawType":"java.lang.String","association":false,"owner":{"idProperty":{"name":"id","rawType":"java.lang.String","association":false,"owner":{"idProperty":{"name":"id","rawType":"java.lang.String","association":false,"owner":{"idProperty":{"name":"id","rawType":"java.lang.String","association":false,"owner":{"idProperty":{"name":"id","rawType":"java.lang.String","association":false,"owner":{"idProperty":
```

With the following errors in Spring's log:

```
2020-08-06 18:11:20.968  WARN 9932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failure while trying to resolve exception [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendError(ResponseFacade.java:472) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.sendServerError(DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java:550) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.handleHttpMessageNotWritable(DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java:440) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveException(DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java:210) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:141) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:80) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1300) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1111) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

2020-08-06 18:11:20.979 ERROR 9932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.CachingMongoPersistentProperty["owner"]->org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity["idProperty"]->org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.CachingMongoPersistentProperty["owner"]->org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity["idProperty"]->org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.CachingMongoPersistentProperty["owner"]->org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity["idProperty"]->org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.CachingMongoPersistentProperty["owner"]->org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity["idProperty"]->org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.CachingMongoPersistentProperty["owner"]->org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity["idProperty"]-> ... IT GOES ON AND ON LIKE THIS ... ->org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity["idProperty"])] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:773) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:755) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]

    ... IT GOES ON LIKE THIS FOR DOZENS AND DOZENS OF LINE

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:755) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]

2020-08-06 18:11:21.553 ERROR 9932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.e.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$StaticView : Cannot render error page for request [/foos/search/query] and exception [] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code.
```

If if return the contents of `var page = repository.findByName(name, pageable);` instead of `var model = pagedResourcesAssembler.toModel(page, resourceAssembler);`, I get the following result:

```
{"content":[{"id":"56a8a8d5daffd28c9c907974","name":"qc"}],"pageable":{"sort":{"sorted":false,"unsorted":true,"empty":true},"offset":0,"pageNumber":0,"pageSize":20,"paged":true,"unpaged":false},"last":true,"totalPages":1,"totalElements":1,"size":20,"number":0,"sort":{"sorted":false,"unsorted":true,"empty":true},"numberOfElements":1,"first":true,"empty":false}
```

So the circular mess comes from the serialization `pagedResourcesAssembler.toModel(page, resourceAssembler)` (and probably the WebMvcConfigurer override).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same `StackOverflowError: null` when I call `PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.toModel(Object)`. My code returns a single `EntityModel` instead of a `PagedModel`. My problem is solved by switching to `PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.toFullResource(Object)`.

The `toModel(Object)` uses excerpt projection while  `toFullResource(Object)` does not. I don't have time to dig into the code to check what produces an infinite loop to cause stack overflow.

Look at the source code of `PagedResourcesAssembler`, `PagedResourcesAssembler.toModel(Page, RepresentationModelAssembler)` calls `RepresentationModelAssember.toModel(Object)`.

So workaround 1 is copying the source code of `PagedResourcesAssembler.toModel(Page, RepresentationModelAssembler)` and use `RepresentationModelAssember.toFullResource(Object)`.

Workaround 2 is extending the `PagedResourcesAssembler` and   overriding the `createModel(...)` method.

Before making the workaround, I have one question. Why do you pass a `PersistentEntityResourceAssembler` to `PagedResourcesAssembler`? My code uses `PersistentEntityResourceAssembler` to add HTTP headers `ETag` and `Last-Modified` when my custom controller returns a single resource. What good does it have to use `PersistentEntityResourceAssembler` to build the response of a collection resource (paged resource)?

Comment: `PagedResourcesAssembler` uses the given resourceassembler to convert each element of the Page into a resource (with its own set of links). Using `PersistentEntityResourceAssembler`  allows me to define custom controllers for each of my domain entity without defining my a assembler for each domain class. This way the response format of my controllers is consistent with the response format of controllers generated by Spring.

Comment: Understand that you want to write less `RepresentationModelAssembler`. But writing Assembler is more elegant than the hacking workaround described in my answer. :)

Comment: RepresentationModelAssember::toFullResource didn't help, but using custom assemblers worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this thread on Spring JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-838?focusedCommentId=154076&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-154076), I was able to:

- convert the controller `MultiValueMap` parameters to a `Predicate`
- use a `RepositoryRestController` instead of a `RestController`, ie be able to inject a `PersistentEntityResourceAssembler` into the controller method.

Custom models and models assembler, as suggested in the accepted answer, are not necessary.

Configure a `QuerydslPredicateBuilder` bean:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class QueryDslConfiguration {

    private final ConversionService mvcConversionService;
    private final QuerydslBindingsFactory querydslBindingsFactory;

    @Bean
    public QuerydslPredicateBuilder querydslPredicateBuilder() {
        return new QuerydslPredicateBuilder(mvcConversionService, querydslBindingsFactory.getEntityPathResolver());
    }

}
```

A service to convert a MultiValueMap to a Predicate:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class PredicateService {

    private final QuerydslPredicateBuilder querydslPredicateBuilder;
    private final QuerydslBindingsFactory querydslBindingsFactory;

    public <T> Predicate getPredicateFromParameters(final MultiValueMap<String, String> parameters, Class<T> tClass) {
        TypeInformation<T> typeInformation = ClassTypeInformation.from(tClass);
        return querydslPredicateBuilder.getPredicate(typeInformation,
                parameters,
                querydslBindingsFactory.createBindingsFor(typeInformation));
    }
}
```

Use the converter in a controller:

```
@RepositoryRestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FooController {

    private final FooRepository repository;
    private final PredicateService predicateService;

    @GetMapping("/foos/search/query")
    public PagedModel<Foo> query(
            @RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> parameters,
            Pageable pageable,
            PersistentEntityResourceAssembler resourceAssembler) {
        Predicate predicate = predicateService.getPredicateFromParameters(parameters, Foo.class);
        Page<Parameter> page = repository.findAll(predicate, 

        return pagedResourcesAssembler.toModel(page, resourceAssembler);
    }

}
```